# Pass Spinner Selected Items from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, bundle, android-spinner

Do not understand fully fragment life-cycle.

**Case:**

> Click `FrameLayout` from `Activity` to move to `Fragment` is working.

**Problem:**

> In `Fragment` there are two `spinners` and one `SubmitButton`, when selected both  `spinner` values, the clicking of`SubmitButton`, should display those values from spinner back to the `Activity's` two `Textviews` . But, I am unable to do that.

**My Solution:**

> I tried to use `Intent`, `putExtras` and then `getExtras` , but as we are in `Fragment`, `Intent` is not going to work for `Fragment`. `Bundle` also not helping.

**P.S.** Need someone who understand good Fragment's life-cycle. Read many posts from stackoverflow and other tutorials. Not found what I meant.

**Do not want external libraries as such eventBus**

Comment: write interface to pass values

Comment: When you are in a fragment you can use a callback, or getting the reference to the Activity using `getActivity()` or `getContext()` and pass the value back calling a specific method in the Activity

Comment: Create `Fragment` from `android studio` and you will see example with interface that you can use to send data to activity.  Right click on package New -> Fragment

Comment: I have read that post @Akshay, It differs from my case. otherwise, I would not have asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you can do that

1) Casting **getActivity()** as your Activity and call the specific method and pass parameter.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public void setData(String value){
        // do whatever with the data
  }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

   public void someMethod(){
     ((MyActivity)getActivity).setData(your_data);
   }
}
```

2) Create an **interface** and pass the value to activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SpinnerListener{

  @Override
  public void onSpinnerItemSelected(String value){
        // do whatever with the data
  }

  public interface SpinnerListener {
    void onSpinnerItemSelected(String value);
  }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SpinnerListener spinnerListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceOf MyActivity)
           spinnerListener = ((MyActivity)context);
    }

   public void someMethod() {
      if(spinnerListener != null)
        spinnerListener.onSpinnerItemSelected(your_data); 
   }
}
```

Note: The safe method is using interface.

Comment: I can call from Activity my fragment, but how abt send from Fragment to Activity? I am not sure with fragment

Comment: I'll post example wait.

Comment: I am still in trouble not handling my case @Bhuvanesh Bs

Comment: I'll post interface method soon

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Finally, done. it works now.

Comment: Sounds good... Happy coding :)